# SliderValueChanged unrecognized selector sent to instance crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I have a `UIViewController` `QuoteViewController` that has a `UITableView`. Inside the `UITableView` is a custom `UITableViewCell` called `excessTableViewCell`.

In story board I have created a custom tableview cell and assigned the custom class to `excessTableViewCell` and I have hooked the slider `IBAction` up with a `ValideDidChange`

This is what **excessTableViewCell.m** looks like.

```
#import "ExcessTableViewCell.h"

@implementation ExcessTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    self.excessLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@", self.excessString];

}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

- (IBAction)excessValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
    UISlider *MySlider = (UISlider *)sender;

    int SliderValue = (int)(MySlider.value/10) * 10;

    self.excessLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %d", SliderValue];
}

@end
```

This is what my `QuoteViewController` tableview cell for row looks like.

```
// slider
        NSString *cellIDString = @"excessCell1";

        self.excessTableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIDString forIndexPath:indexPath];

        // Configure the cell...
        self.excessTableViewCell.excessSlider.maximumValue = 2000;
        self.excessTableViewCell.excessSlider.value = 2000 / 2;

        NSInteger halfValue = 2000 / 2;

        self.excessTableViewCell.excessLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %ld", (long)halfValue];
        return self.excessTableViewCell;
```

Effectively as soon as I try to slide the value the app crashes and produces the following error.

This is what my error looks like:

```
2017-04-08 17:12:08.863831 Insuriato[17401:3848405]
-[QuoteViewController sliderValueChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1005423f0 2017-04-08 17:18:57.449734 Insuriato[17401:3848405] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[QuoteViewController sliderValueChanged:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1005423f0'
*** First throw call stack: (0x1860f51b8 0x184b2c55c 0x1860fc268 0x1860f9270 0x185ff280c 0x18bfdfd30 0x18bfdfcb0 0x18bfca128 0x18c387758 0x18bfe7974 0x18c56a628 0x18c5666c0 0x18c5661e0 0x18c56549c 0x18bfda30c 0x18bfaada0 0x18c79475c 0x18c78e130 0x1860a2b5c 0x1860a24a4 0x1860a00a4 0x185fce2b8 0x187a82198 0x18c0157fc 0x18c010534 0x100087a3c 0x184fb15b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: `sliderValueChanged` and `excessValueChanged` are not the same name.

Comment: The error says that it cant find 'sliderValueChanged:' method on 'QuoteViewController'. Check if you have assigned some IBOutlet that is connected to 'sliderValueChanged:'.

Comment: Have you previously deleted and reassigned the event/IBoutlet?? Check if have duplicate or existing reference on slider.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy it turned out because I had copied an old table view cell even though I had assigned the correct table view class it was still registering the old class methods.